# How to create pdf and review in flutter

Tags: pdf, flutter, dart

I'm trying to create pdf and review it.

I applied [pdf](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf) plugin for creating the pdf , [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) plugin for save the pdf to the device's storage and
 [flutter_full_pdf_viewer](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_full_pdf_viewer) plugin for view the pdf.

I have followed [create-a-pdf-in-flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50391699/create-a-pdf-in-flutter). 
But getting errors in the code if I try to import with `import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart';`  , material element isn't working `import 'package:flutter/material.dart';` .

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:pdfdemo/pages/pdf_viewer.dart';
//import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart'
```

Variable:

```
final pdf = Document();
```

Creating pdf file page:

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("PDF CREATE"),
      actions: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.save),
          onPressed: () => savePdfFile(),
        )
      ],),
      body: pdf.addPage(Page(
      pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
      build: (BuildContext context) {
        return Center(
          child: Text("Hello Flutter"),
        );
      })),
    );
```

Saving pdf file to the device's location:

```
savePdfFile()async{
    final dir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
    print("Directoryyyyyyyyy:${dir.path}");
    final String path = "${dir.path}/example.pdf";
    final file = File(path);
    await file.writeAsBytes(pdf.save());
     Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => PgfViewerPage(path: path))
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The Problem in your code is that you are using the material library and the PDF library at the same time. The Widgets that are provided by the PDF plugin dont work in the regular Scaffold from flutter. You build your PDF with them like they are showing in the example. To get the PDF file you need to generate it first and then pass it to the screen where you wanna display it.

Try it like this, it worked for me

```
        Future<File> createPDF(){
         final Document pdf = Document();
            pdf.addPage(
                //Your PDF design here with the widget system of the plugin
MultiPage(
      pageFormat:
          PdfPageFormat.letter.copyWith(marginBottom: 1.5 * PdfPageFormat.cm),
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      theme: Theme(
        tableHeader: TextStyle(fontSize: 8.0),
        tableCell: TextStyle(fontSize: 8.0),
      ),
      header: (Context context) {
        if (context.pageNumber == 1) {
          return null;
        }
        return Container(
            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 3.0 * PdfPageFormat.mm),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 3.0 * PdfPageFormat.mm),
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                border:
                    BoxBorder(bottom: true, width: 0.5, color: PdfColors.grey)),
            child: Text('VCR',
                style: Theme.of(context)
                    .defaultTextStyle
                    .copyWith(color: PdfColors.grey)));
      },
    );


        output = await getTemporaryDirectory();
          final file = File('${output.path}/example.pdf');
          file.writeAsBytesSync(pdf.save());
        return file;
        }
```

After you created the PDF display it in a scaffold like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_full_pdf_viewer/full_pdf_viewer_scaffold.dart';


    class PDFScreen extends StatelessWidget {
      final String pathPDF;
      PDFScreen({this.pathPDF});

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return PDFViewerScaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text("Document"),
              actions: <Widget>[
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.share),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ],
            ),
            path: pathPDF);
      }
    }
```

the pathPDf you get from the first function if you call file.absolute.path

IMPORTANT: the function and the PDFScreen must be in separate files!! Where you implement the function for generating the PDF you MUST NOT import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

hope this helps

Comment: So sir, How & from the where  you are calling the function `createPDF()`  means from which class ? Please provide some more code, I'm  still not understanding properly.

Comment: Before you call The Navigator function to go to your pdf viewing creen you call createPDF() and have the path to the file as an arguement for the Navigator

Comment: Okay sir, I understood but If i do not import 'package:flutter/material.dart'; then build() , materialApp() , IconButton() and etc will not work.

Comment: you are not supposed to cal them in the same file. create a new file with a helper class und then call it before you push the navigation class

Comment: i used syncfusion_flutter_pdf: ^18.4.48-beta to create pdf and then used flutter_full_pdf_viewer: ^1.0.6 for viewing  the pdf .

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:image_gallery_saver/image_gallery_saver.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart' as intl;
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:screenshot/screenshot.dart';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_pdf/pdf.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:open_file/open_file.dart';
 // Will take screenshot of the widget and save in Unit8List and create pdf of //Unit8List
    //paste this function where needed
    openPDFofSS();
    //Add controller
     ScreenshotController screenshotController = ScreenshotController();
    //define controller before in widget as
    Screenshot(
  controller: screenshotController,
  child: Text("replace child with the widget you want to convert in pdf"),
),
    
    // paste these function 
    
      Future<void> openPDFofSS() async {
        await screenshotController.capture().then((Uint8List image) {
          //Capture Done
          setState(() {
            pdfLoading = true;
            //save screenshot into Uint8List image
            _imageFile = image;
            //convert Unit8List image into PDF
            _convertImageToPDF();
            saveImage(_imageFile);
          });
        }).catchError((onError) {
          print(onError);
        });
      }
    
    
      Future<void> _convertImageToPDF() async {
        //Create the PDF document
        PdfDocument document = PdfDocument();
        //Add the page
        PdfPage page = document.pages.add();
        //Load the image.
        final PdfImage image = PdfBitmap(_imageFile);
        //draw image to the first page
        page.graphics.drawImage(
            image, Rect.fromLTWH(-20, -20, page.size.width - 50, page.size.height));
        //Save the docuemnt
        List<int> bytes = document.save();
        //Dispose the document.
        document.dispose();
        //Get external storage directory
        Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
        //Get directory path
        String path = directory.path;
        //Create an empty file to write PDF data
        File file = File('$path/Output.pdf');
    
        //Write PDF data
        await file.writeAsBytes(bytes, flush: true);
        print(path);
        //Open the PDF document in mobile
        OpenFile.open('$path/Output.pdf');
        setState(() {
          pdfLoading = false;
        });
      }
      Future<String> saveImage(Uint8List image) async {
        await [Permission.storage].request();
        final result = await ImageGallerySaver.saveImage(image, name: 'autosmart');
        return result['filePath'];
      }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).